# What's Wrong In My DFS Code?

Tags: c++, depth-first-search

I have tried to Implement Recursive DFS as I found at TH Cormen's Book . I implemented the Algorithm . But the program Crashed . Here is my Code:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

vector<int>graph[100];
int tim;
int start[100], finish[100], path[100], color[100];

void DFS_Visit(int u)
{
    color[u] = 0;
    tim = tim + 1;
    start[u] = tim;
    for(int i=0; i<graph[u].size(); i++)
    {
        int v = graph[u][i];
        if(color[v]=-1)
        {
            path[v] = u;
            DFS_Visit(v);
        }
    }
    color[u] = 1;
    tim = tim + 1;
    finish[u] = tim;
}

int main()
{
    int nodes, edges, u, v;
    cin>>nodes>>edges;
    for(int i=0; i<edges; i++)
    {
        cin>>u>>v;
        graph[u].push_back(v);
        graph[v].push_back(u);
    }
    for(int i=1; i<=nodes; i++)
    {
        color[i] = -1;
        path[i] = -1;
        //cout<<'1'<<endl;
    }
    tim = 0;
    for(int i=1; i<=nodes; i++)
    {
        //cout<<'1'<<endl;
        if(color[i]==-1)
        {
            DFS_Visit(i);
        }
    }
    for(int i=1; i<=nodes; i++)
    {
        printf("Node %d: Starting_Time: %d || Finishing Time: %d\n", i, start[i], finish[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone please learn me What's wrong with my Code? What to do to resolve this Problem . I have written the Code as TH Cormen's Algorithm Book .

Comment: Where is the crash? Have you tried debugging it? A little more information would go a long way.

Comment: At DFS_Visit() Function. @DominicMcDonnell

Comment: What line was the crash on?

Comment: The Crash is Caused Because Unknown Times Looping int That Function .... How to debug this Problem .....

Comment: The Crash is Caused Because Unknown Times Looping int That Function .... How to debug this Problem ..... [May be For Base Case] @DominicMcDonnell

Comment: Its a Normal DFS Code . Just to learn DFS . Never it will greater than 100

Comment: I can't see anything obviously wrong. You haven't given me the line that it is crashing on, or the data that is causing it to crash, and I don't know the context of the code and what it is trying to achieve. Your best bet is to load it up in a debugger and step through, either to give us more info or to figure it out yourself.

Comment: One note, just because it is written in a book, doesn't mean that is correct and fully debugged. Plus it is very easy to make errors when typing in code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have Got My error . That is

> if(color[v]=-1) will be if(color[v]==-1)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one problem

```
if(color[v]=-1)
```

That is setting `color[v]` to `-1`.

I am surprised your compiler didn't generate a warning for this.

Comment: Yes i got this error just 10 minutes ago......I am using Code blocks ....  And no warning here ..